# problems displaying json data retrieved using php curl

Tags: php, json, curl

First, thanks for you reading. Here is my code

what my json data looks like when viewed in a browser using the url,

```
{
  "$totalResults": 1500,
  "$startIndex": 1,
  "$itemsPerPage": 3,
  "$resources": [
    {
      "$uuid": "5e7b9312-52e5-4fe1-b3e4-633ca04c9764",
      "$httpStatus": "OK",
      "$descriptor": "",
      "name": "Heinz Tomato Sauce  Sachets Qty 200"
    },
    {
      "$uuid": "1a0f9dca-c417-4cff-94d2-99d16438723f",
      "$httpStatus": "OK",
      "$descriptor": "",
      "name": "Heinz Brown Sauce Sachet Qty 200"
    },
    {
      "$uuid": "126fdb17-81ce-41b4-bdba-91d0a170262a",
      "$httpStatus": "OK",
      "$descriptor": "",
      "name": "Heinz English Mustard  Sachets Qty 300"
    }
  ]
}
```

test2.php

```
<?php

// SAGE URL
$url = 'http://localhost:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/-/commodities?select=name&count=3&format=json';

//SAGE USERNAME & PASSWORD
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test';


    //initiaize
$ch = curl_init();

    //set options       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);        

    //execute 
$result = curl_exec($ch);

    //close curl session / free resources
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result);

foreach ($json->{'$resources'} as $mydata) {
    echo $mydata->name;
};

?>
```

errors im getting

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sage Json\test2.php on line 29

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sage Json\test2.php on line 29
```

I’m not sure what's going wrong, this works if i get the same data from a file but not if I’m retrieving it from at rest server, and if anyone could shed some light I would be grateful

Comment: check what is coming in $json and $result variable.

Comment: not sure what to use, i did a ver_dump( isset( ) ); and &results has stuff inside it but $json does not im not sure how come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im really sorry for never getting back to you. so it turn out that when you get data from the sage service, it returned to you in "utf 8 bom".

So before i can display any thing i needed to remove the format by clearing the first three characters with in the array. with the substr() function.

```
$json_data = substr($json_data, 3);
```

Thank you all for helping with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ajking11 the reason your getting Invalid argument supplied for foreach() is that $json vairiable is overwritten and has no data try somthing like this

```
<?php

// SAGE URL
$url = 'http://localhost:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/-/commodities?select=name&count=3';

//SAGE USERNAME & PASSWORD
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test';


//initiaize
$ch = curl_init();

//set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//execute
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close curl session / free resources
curl_close($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$data = json_encode($xml);
$arr = json_decode($data,TRUE);


foreach ($arr['entry'] as $k=>$v){
    echo $v; // etc.
}
```

note that I have removed &format=json and encoded later hope this help let me know how your getting on

Comment: I have been doing a little more research on this and it seem that the $result part of $json_decode is not valid json code so returns null

Answer (score 2):

you might like to use this code and refine it to your needs

```
<?php
    // SAGE URL
        //$url = 'http://computer_2:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/-/commodities?select=name&count=3&select=name&count=10&format=json';
        $url ='http://localhost:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/-/tradingAccounts?select=name&count=10';
        //SAGE USERNAME & PASSWORD
        $username = 'MANAGER';
        $password = '';

        //initiaize
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

        //execute
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        //close curl session / free resources
        curl_close($ch);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);



foreach($xml->xpath("//sdata:payload") as $entry) {
    // xpath here must be from payload to tradingAccount
    $content = $entry->xpath("./crm:tradingAccount");
    foreach($content as $c) {
       // Make set of children with prefix crm
       $nodes = $c->children('crm', true); 
       echo $nodes->reference . " | " . $nodes->name . " / " . $nodes->openedDate . "<br />\n";

    }
}
```

thanks PHPhil and splash58 for your assistance with the namespace issue

Answer (score 2):

As Artful_dodger say's the json is the problem here is how I would solve it

```
<?php

// SAGE URL
$url = 'http://localhost:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/-/commodities?select=name&count=3&format=json';

//SAGE USERNAME & PASSWORD
$username = 'MANAGER';
$password = '';


//initiaize
$ch = curl_init();

//set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//execute
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close curl session / free resources
curl_close($ch);

// doing a substring as there are 3 weird characters being passed back from IIS in front of the string
$json = json_decode(substr($result, 3, strlen($result)), true);


    foreach ($json['$resources'] as $mydata) {
        echo $mydata['name'] . "<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP `json_decode` function returns an array and not an object, so instead of using

```
foreach ($json->{'$resources'} as $mydata) {
    echo $mydata->name;
};
```

you should use

```
foreach ($json['$resources'] as $mydata) {
    echo $mydata['name'];
};
```

UPDATE

your `test2.php` should look like this:

```
<?php

// SAGE URL
$url = 'http://localhost:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/-/commodities?select=name&count=3&format=json';

//SAGE USERNAME & PASSWORD
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test';


//initiaize
$ch = curl_init();

//set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//execute
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close curl session / free resources
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result);
$json = (array)$json;

foreach ($json['$resources'] as $mydata) {
    echo $mydata->name . "<br>";
};
```

in your code the major problem was in naming of the JSON attribute `$resources`: it is named as PHP variable and it causes the problem.

Converting the decoded variable into an array solves the problem as the associative array key is a string.

Comment: changing the foreach give back:
`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sage Json\test2.php on line 29`

Comment: Were you able to resolve the invalid Character at the beginning of your json file which is causing the above response